# XML Schema (XSD) 1.0 xs:pattern regex to match 4 digits as a string?

Tags: xml, regex-negation, xsd-1.0

How can I match a specific sequence of digits as if it were a string in an XML Schema `xs:pattern`?

Say I have some tags containing arbitrary 10-character strings like

`<string>12345678990</string>`

And I want to rule out all tags with a specific blacklist of arbitrary sequences like `1234`, `2435`, ``9587`, or some such.

How do I address the specific 4-digit sub-string in order to negate it and add it to a list of `xs:pattern` restrictions for `<string>`'s content model?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any practical XSD-compliant regular expression that will match all strings except those containing "1234" as a substring. (And therefore your more challenging requirement of banning several substrings also cannot be met).

This is one for XSD 1.1 assertions, for example

```
<xs:assert test="not(contains($value, '1234') or contains($value, '9999'))"/>
```