# XSD 1.1 assertion to exclude all (sub-)strings matching a pattern?

Tags: regex, function, regex-negation, xsd-1.1

I want to write an XSD 1.1 assertion as in the similar question [XML Schema (XSD) 1.0 xs:pattern regex to match 4 digits as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871700/xml-schema-xsd-1-0-xspattern-regex-to-match-4-digits-as-a-string) - but this time for a specified *pattern* corresponding to a large set of possible substrings, written as an XSD-compliant regex, e.g.:

```
AZ09{10}
```

Is that possible given the XSD 1.1 functions `not(contains())`?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you can just use `not(matches())`